# Do you need a visa to enter the US to catch another flight?

Tags: air-travel, miami

Here's the situation: I want to bring my girlfriend over here to Portugal for the holidays. She's Venezuelan but is in Trinidad and Tobago right now. My plan is to save money by buying 2 different plane tickets, one from Trinidad to Miami, and another one from Miami to Portugal. My question is, does she need a visa to stay in the US for 3 hours to catch another flight?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, she needs a C-1 visa to change planes in the US, because the US has no exit border controls, so domestic and international flights aren't segregated in the departures area. In addition, it is possible to exit the departures area without any checks.

Thus, anyone touching down at a US airport **must** enter the US.

This fact is stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=us&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=tw&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by Airlines.

> There are no TWOV facilities available in the USA

(TWOV=transit without visa)

Comment: The physical layout of airports is not the cause of the visa requirement. There used to be TWOV available in the US, but the practice was ended several years ago.

Comment: @phoog Well, back then pax boarded planes from two locations, one for transiting pax and one for others. Without this arrangement, the physical layout of the airports **does** make it impossible to introduce TWOV. To make it possible, one would have to make it impossible to leave the departures area once airside, **and** require some form of biometric capture for all passengers clearing security, which would then be verified if boarding a domestic flight.

Comment: @Crazydre: Canada also doesn't have exit controls, but Canada does have [TWOV](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/index.asp) for nationals of a few Asian countries.

Comment: @crazydre It depends if the country is willing to tolerate the risk of individuals absconding. For instance in the U.K. some people are allowed to change airports without a visa but would require a visa to enter the UK for other purposes.

Comment: @Calchas Which obviously the US isn't

Comment: Before September 11, the US _did_ have TWOV. Passengers from a variety of countries were allowed to transit landside if they had an onward ticket. There was no difference in airport layout between then and now. This was one of the things eliminated after the attacks; it was gone by 2005 or so. And @user102008 Canada is physically changing its airports to allow for TWOV, at least to US preclearance. There are now dedicated transit lanes that bypass Canada immigration and go directly to US preclearance in most (or maybe all, by now) Canadian airports which have US preclearance.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Vancouver, Calgary and Toronto terminal 1. However, like you said, those Airports have dedicated corridors, unlike US Airports other than Anchorage (specifically for pax on the Cathay flight Hong Kong-Toronto, which makes a fuel stop there)

Comment: @Crazydre TWOV involved clearing immigration without a visa. The rules were different, not the airports (you surely realize that the US hasn't replaced or reconfigured all of its international airports in the last 15 years!). People were simply allowed, given certain circumstances, to clear passport control for the purpose of transit without having a valid visa.

Comment: @phoog Guess they simply tolerated the risk of people absconding back then, seeing as Things were more relaxed pre-9/11.

Comment: @Calchas, Crazydre, a *higher* risk, yes. Even those *with* visas abscond, of course. It happens all the time. One report estimates that half a million people overstayed in 2015, nearly 1400 every day.